# Parse flat json into array with categories

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

i need to dynamically parse this flat JSON:

```
    [{"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"cortecaballero","monto":"12"},
    {"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"cortedama","monto":"15"},
    {"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"corteniño","monto":"10"},
    {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tintecaballero","monto":"12"},
    {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tintedama","monto":"15"},
    {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tinteniño","monto":"10"},
    {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadocaballero","monto":"12"},
    {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadodama","monto":"15"},
    {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadoniño","monto":"10"}]
```

Into an array in this way:

```
 ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
     items.add(new SectionItem("prueba 1"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("cortecaballero", "12"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("cortedama", "15"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("corteniño", "12"));
     items.add(new SectionItem("prueba 2"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("tintecaballero", "12"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("tintedama", "15"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("tinteniño", "12"));
     items.add(new SectionItem("prueba 3"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("secadocaballero", "12"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("secadodama", "15"));
     items.add(new EntryItem("secadoniño", "12"));
```

I've tried but always "titulo" gets repeated on every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's better to change the format of your `JSON`, but in case it you don't have a chance to do that and if the structure of response is always the same as above, the possible solution is to do the following (assuming `out` is `JSON` response of type `String`):

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(out);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (!tempSet.contains(jsonObject.getString("titulo"))){
        items.add(new SectionItem(jsonObject.getString("titulo")));
        tempSet.add(jsonObject.getString("titulo"));
    }
    items.add(new EntryItem(jsonObject.getString("nombrelinea"), jsonObject.getString("monto")));
}
```

P.S. Edit was made to reflect the issue described in comments

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Something i forgot to say: the JSON comes as string from a database and its size can vary. I tell you this because your answer is for a fixed-size json. Thanks again!

Comment: I testes your solution but only works if the json is static, but the number of objects will vary. Can you help me with a dynamic solution?

Comment: @eligdt can you please show another one example of json you get?

Comment: ok, here's another example!
[{"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"cortecaballero","monto":"12"},
    {"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"cortedama","monto":"15"},
    {"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"corteniño","monto":"10"},
    {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tintecaballero","monto":"12"},
    {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tintedama","monto":"15"},
    {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"tinteniño","monto":"10"},
    {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadocaballero","monto":"12"},
    {"titulo":"prueba4","nombrelinea":"secadodama","monto":"15"},]

Comment: It's never the same amount of objects who share the same "titulo" data, it can vary.

Comment: @eligdt I've updated the code, please check if it works for you

Comment: Sorry but it keeps showing SectionItem on every EntryItem, not just on the first. Do you want me to post full code?

Comment: @eligdt it's unclear for me what's the general rule for adding elements to the `items` list. Now loop traverses `JSONArray` and adding only unique `titulo` as `SectionItem` and every `EntryItem`

Comment: The rule is this:
- If SectionItem string was already added,add EntryItem
- Else, add SectionItem
Example:
- Add Prueba1
- Add cortecaballero, 12
- dont add again Prueba1
- Add cortedama, 15
- Add Prueba2
- add tintecaballero, 12
And so on... dinamically.
Is that posiible? And thanks for your constant help!

Comment: @eligdt OK, I've made a correction. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you so much! I'm new here, so i can't vote you up but i accept it. Thanks!